# Javascript, Is there any way to debug/find out where a specific elements property is inherited from?

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, properties

I have a  element who's computed style font-size is "16px".  I'm trying to find where in the CSS or javascript this is set (like on which of "td"s parent elements).  I tried in the console something like

```
var td = document.querySelectorAll("td")[0];
var parent = td.parentNode;
while (td.tagName != "BODY") { console.log(td.className, td.style.fontSize); td = parent; parent = parent.parentNode } 

That didn't work.  Is there any way to do this?  Thanks a ton!
```

Comment: Why do you want to find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as CSS goes, it's easy and usually right next to Computed Styles.

Example: Chrome will [do this for you](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles).

Right click on the desired element and select "Inspect Element".

In the styles tab at the right, there will be certain properties it currently has and if you scroll down enough, you will see (if applicable), sections that say `Inherited from` and then a class, id, or element group.